# How to get sum and count of specific column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'percent':[0.5, 0.2, -0.2, 0.5 ],
                   'amt':[10, 5, -5, 10]})
```

```
percent    amt
0.5         10
0.2         5  
-0.2        -5
0.5         10
```

I want to get the count of rows where percentage is ">0", percentage "<0" and the sum of amount column.

Desired results

```
percentage '>0' = 3
percentage '<0' = 1
amt = 20
```

I tried

```
df[df.percent > 0].count()
df[df.percent < 0].count()
df['amt'].sum()
```

But this is returning something else and not as my desired result of a single value.

Comment: `df["percent"].gt(0).sum()`; `df["percent"].lt(0).sum()`; `df["amt"].sum()`

Comment: `count` gives you the number of non-null values, so it doesn't care about whether the answer is True or False, they still `count`

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
print(df[df['percent']>0].shape[0])    #Rows with % > 0               
print(df[df['percent']<0].shape[0])    #Rows with % < 0               
print(df['amt'].sum())                 #Sum of amount
```

**Output:**

```
3
1
20
```